# Sticky Element in Absolute Positioned Parent Element Jiggles

Tags: html, css, sticky

For my project, I'm trying to place an element (Table of Content) in an absolute position next to a block of text, I want the ToC to remain on the side as the user scrolls.

So to do this, I placed the TOC as a sticky element inside a parent wrapper that is in absolute position.

However, I notice that whenever I scroll, the TOC slightly "jiggles", and I could not for the life of me figure out why that is happening. I recreated this problem on codepen. You might have to zoom in a bit to notice the jiggle.

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/dingdingho/pen/abQpbpo

Snippet:

```css
html,
body {
 margin:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 font-size:16px;
 text-size-adjust:none;
}
body {
 -moz-tab-size:4;
 tab-size:4;
 overflow-wrap:break-word;
 word-wrap:break-word;
 line-height:1.618;
}
.container {
 min-height:100%;
 min-width:100%;
 position:relative
}
.main {
 padding:2em 1em 15em;
 display:block
}
.main {
 padding-top:7em
}
.main-inner {
 margin:0 auto;
 display:block
}
.header {
 z-index:3
}
.header {
 position:fixed;
 width:100vw
}
.header-wrapper {
 padding:1em 0;
}
.header-inner {
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
 align-items:center;
 margin:0 auto;
 max-width:45em
}
.header-inner.list {
 max-width:45em
}
.site-brand {
 margin-right:1em
}
.brand {
 font-size:1.9em;
 text-decoration:none
}
.nav-toggle {
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:1em;
 right:1em;
 margin-right:1em;
 width:1em;
 height:1em;
 cursor:pointer
}
.nav {
 z-index:3;
 position:relative
}
.menu {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 list-style:none;
 line-height:1.5;
 font-weight:500
}
.menu-item {
 display:inline-block
}
.menu-item a {
 color:var(--color-contrast-medium)
}
.menu-item a:hover {
 color:var(--color-primary)
}
.active a {
 color:var(--color-primary)
}
.nav {
 text-align:right;
 font-size:80%
}
.menu-item {
 margin-left:0.5em
}
.menu-item .icon {
 margin:0 0.3em 0.2em 0
}
.term-count {
 color:var(--color-contrast-medium);
 font-size:0.7em
}
.single .main-inner {
 width:45em
}
.post-title {
 text-align:center
}
.post-body {
 margin-top:5em !important
}
.post p {
 margin:1em 0;
 line-height:2
}
.caption {
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 margin:-1em 0 0;
 font-size:90%;
 color:var(--color-contrast-medium)
}
.contents {
 margin-top:5em
}
.contents ol,
.contents ul {
 list-style:none
}
ol.toc,
ul.toc {
 padding:0;
 overflow:auto hidden;
 white-space:nowrap
}
.main {
 padding-top:6em;
 padding-bottom:11em
}
.header-wrapper {
 padding-bottom:0
}
.menu-item {
 margin-left:0.8em
}
.nav {
 font-size:85%
}
.contents {
 margin-top:2em
}
.new-toc {
 position:sticky;
 top:100px;
 left:0;
 width:180px;
 line-height:2em;
 word-wrap:break-word;
 box-sizing:border-box
}

.sidebar {
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 height:98%;
 display:block;
 transform:translateX(-100%)
}
.toc {
 overflow:auto !important
}
ol ol {
 display:none
}
ol .has-active>ol {
 display:block
}
.a-active {
 color:var(--color-primary);
 transition:0s !important
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="header-container">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="header-wrapper">
                <div>
                    <div class="header-inner single  box-shadow ">
                        <div class="site-brand">
                            <a href="../../" class="brand">Brand Name</a>
                        </div>
                        <nav class="nav">
                            <ul class="menu" id="menu">
                                <li class="menu-item active"><a href="../../writings/"><span
                                            class="menu-item-name">Menu Item</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div id="main-container">
        <main class="main single" id="main">
            <div class="sidebar" style="left: 510px; top: 147.879px; transform: translateX(-100%);">
                <div class="new-toc">
                    <nav class="contents">
                        <h4 id="contents" class="contents-title">Contents</h4>
                        <ol class="toc">
                            <li>TOC Link</li>
                        </ol>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-inner">
                <article class="content post h-entry" data-small-caps="true" data-align="default" data-type="writings">
                    <h1 class="post-title p-name">Title</h1>
                    <div class="post-body e-content">
                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.    
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.     
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.     
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.    
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.     
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.     
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Relevant section

```
>! sidebar is the absolutely positioned element
>! new-toc is the sticky positioned element

           <div class="sidebar" style="left: 510px; top: 147.879px; transform: translateX(-100%);">
                <div class="new-toc">
                    <nav class="contents">
                        <h4 id="contents" class="contents-title">Contents</h4>
                        <ol class="toc">
                            <li>TOC Link</li>
                        </ol>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I tried debugging by removing the JS, fixed the height of the parent container, etc, but I could  not pin down the root cause for the jiggling behavior

Any response is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I could not notice the "jigling"  https://i.imgur.com/sWuS53o.gif

Comment: Might need to zoom in a bit. 
https://imgur.com/gallery/xwnmSzR
It was pretty noticeable in the actual project :/